# c++ is there a flag for c++17 osx 10.13.6

Tags: c++, macos

I used brew to update to 8.2 gcc but I keep getting this
**error:**

```
error: no member named 'any' in namespace 'std'
```

Comment: Should be `-std=c++17`

Comment: @user4581301  this error still persist   `error: call to unavailable function 'any_cast': introduced in
      macOS 10.14`

Comment: Huh. I don't think I can help you with this. `std::any_cast` should be supported in GCC8.2. See if you can compile the example code at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any . If that works you may have an error somewhere around your use of `any_cast` that's confusing the compiler. You may need to create an [mcve] and ask another question based on the MCVE to let the language lawyers figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google is your friend, so is Wikipedia.

From the [GCC website](https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/projects/cxx-status.html#cxx17), we can see that there is experimental/support for C++17 standard, through the `-std=c++17` flag.

From [this awesome wiki article](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B17_features), there is a cross reference list for functionality and features. It indicates that `std::any` is supported in version `GCC >= 7`, but only on Clang (which may be what you are using on accident) version `Clang >= 4`.

Post the command you are running for some extra help, and make sure you have the corresponding header, included in your file(s).